# Start scroll only after animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, position

I am trying to make an animation where the text moves towards right on scroll but I want to keep the background static until the text moves from initial to final position.

```js
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function(){
jQuery('h1').css("left", Math.max(100 - 0.2*window.scrollY, 1) + "vw");
})
```

```css
.scrolling-text{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100px;
  left: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrolling-text">
  <h1>Moving Text on Scroll</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the code I referred to but the background moves while the text is moving.

Comment: It doesn't look like animation. You want to manually scroll the text, and when the text is completely scrolled, you can scroll the window further. So?

Comment: I made a solution last year. Is this what you want? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446627/horizontal-scroll-pause-carousel/65447145#65447145

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to make a separate horizontally scrolable section. It is simply a displacement from right to left on scroll. It might not be clear but in the example that I've mentioned, the div scrolls while the text is moving which is something I don't want. I want to keep the div fixed until the text moves a few pixels and then resume the normal scrolling.

Comment: Should the animation start right after the page loads?

Comment: No, when the section arrives which is somewhere in the middle of the page.

Comment: But tag h1 is fixed. Please provide more clarification for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and combine it with `position: sticky`.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
$('h1').css("left", Math.max(100 - 0.2*window.scrollY, 1) + "vw");
});
$('.wrap').css('height',$('h1').outerWidth()*2);
```

```css
.scrolling-text{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4158D0;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 50px;
  left: 100vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="scrolling-text">
  <h1>Moving Text on Scroll</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```